# How to redirect user to Unauthorized page in webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

In my Web App I have a few pages where only certain users can access (not using roles)

This is working however when a unauthorized user tries to access a page from the Dashboard page it redirects that user to the same page (like it refreshes the page)

I would like to redirect the user to a page `UnauthorizedAccess.aspx`

I followed this tutorial in setting up my web page with authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

After that I created a folder in my project named `Clients` and in that folder I have a web page named `client1.aspx`  and in the same folder my `Web.config` file

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<location path="Client1.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="User1" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Then in my `Login.aspx` Page

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ReportCenter
{
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
                StatusText.Text = string.Format("Hello {0}!!", 
 User.Identity.GetUserName());
                LoginStatus.Visible = true;
                LogoutButton.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                LoginForm.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var authenticationManager = 
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, 
DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { 
IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            StatusText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
            LoginStatus.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void SignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticationManager = 
 HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
}
```

So when the user logs in initially they are redirected to the dashboard page but when they browse to a page they have not access to it must redirect them to the unauthorized page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe too simple but could you just redirect here on unsuccessful authentication

**EDIT** My mistake I didn't read the question properly :) I see you have a web.config under the Client folder with specific authorization.
I think this will work as you check whether authenticated first then if the return url is not null will mean its coming from a page with auth set (Client1) so redirect then otherwise carry on to `Dashboard.aspx`

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])
   {
      Response.Redirect("UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
   }
   StatusText.Text = string.Format("Hello {0}!!", 
   User.Identity.GetUserName());
   LoginStatus.Visible = true;
   LogoutButton.Visible = true;       
}
else
{
   LoginForm.Visible = true;       
}
```

Comment: All users can login successfully, the problem is when the user tries to acces client1.aspx and haven't got access according to the web.config it must then only redirect.  when I implement your code it goes to unauthorized without getting to the login screen